# How to bake light on objects in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, monogame, lighting

I have searched everywhere on how to bake light in Unity but most answers are for the older versions. Currently I would like to bake the lighting in Unity, and export the baked light for each object as a texture. Then in monogame, directly apply the baked light as texture for the objects.

Is there a way to do so?

Thank you very much.

(I used Unity 2017 for mac, when I select Window->Lighting,there is no lightmapping button)

Answer (score 1):

**To my knowledge, the light in unity is always baked on a per scene basis. Meaning the whole scene shares the same baked file**.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LightMode-Baked.html

Baked lights are fixed and calculated based on the light/shadow settings of your lights, objects and their materials.

However, there is also mixed light and realtime calculated light.

What effect is it you wish to achieve?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer! I would like to export the baked light map on objects as textures, so I can use them directly in monogame (for this project, I'm required to use monogame, but setting up lighting in monogame is much more complicated than unity).

Comment: I don't believe that is possible.

However, you could create an object in Unity and then in its renderer set it to "Shadows only" and then take a screenshot of the shadow and edit that in photoshop. That way you have a texture with a shadow.

It seems to be an impractical way to do it though. I suspect it's better to find a solution adapted to monogame or to use Unity.